# How much does Cheat Code increase Jackpot range?

Tags: dicey-dungeons

The description for the equipment Cheat Code says it will "increase Jackpot range for this turn". How much does it increase jackpot range by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cheat Code increases the Jackpot range by 1. Specifically the target floor is lowered, meaning a jackpot of 13 would become a target range of 12-13.

Note that the upgraded version Cheat Code+ increases Jackpot range by 2 instead of 1.